# Distribution of points on a 5 x 6 rectangle

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics, puzzle, pigeonhole-principle

Prove that if eight points are places in a closed five by six rectangle (closed means that we include the edges) there will be two points that are at most a distance of √10 apart. Use the Pigeon Hole Principle. Type up a formal proof. Be sure to clearly state

(1) What are the pigeons?

(2) How many pigeons are there?

(3) What are the holes?

(4) How many holes are there?

You may draw a picture as part of the proof, but the proof must still be in complete sentences in paragraph form.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please show us your efforts and where you are stuck

Comment: I know the eight points represent the pigeons, I'm just finding the pigeon holes/regions. I know √1^2 + 3^2 = √10 and √10 is the length of the hypotenuse with legs of 1 and 3. I need to know the shape it creates and discover how many regions there are.

Comment: When I did it, I got 5 regions. Is that correct?

Comment: You will likely have $8-1=7$ regions. (I've not been able to find a suitable dissection of the rectangle though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: 6 by 5 rectangle dissection]
Dissect the rectangle into seven cells as shown in the figure.  By the pigeonhole principle, there must be a cell which contains at least two of the eight points. The maximum distance between two points in any one cell is $\sqrt{10}$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you can subdivide the $5 \times 6$ rectangle into 7 rectangles that each have a diagonal shorter than $\sqrt{10}$. Then you can indeed apply the pidgeonhole principle with the points as pidgeons, and the smaller rectangles as holes.